# Is it possible to maintain folder structure and sink files in a mapping data flow?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I need to process multiple files at once in a mapping data flow, but need to maintain the source folder structure when syncing.
In other words, the structure

```
year=yyyy/month=mm/day=dd/files
```

must be maintained on the sink side as well.
Is there a way to configure the sink settings to accomplish this?
Please check the attached folder structure of the source data and the design of the mapping data flow.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you want the processed files to go to similar folder in the sink side , where sink has same folder structure as ource. Also the attachment is, pls attach.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can make the Sink path dynamic in the `Dataset` itself and then use that Dataset in the Sink in Data flow Mapping.

Under `Connection` tab in **Dataset**, for `File path` option use the below dynamic expression:

`@concat(formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyy'),'/',formatDateTime(utcNow(),'MM'),'/',formatDateTime(utcNow(),'dd'),'/')`

[image]

Use the same Dataset in Data flow sink and run the pipeline.

Path will be created with the current `YYYY/MM/dd` format and file will be dumped there. Refer below image.

[image]